# Query Of Queries runtime error - The select column reference [X] is not a column in any of the tables of the FROM table list

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I am trying to apply filter on ColdFusion query, but am always getting an error. Here's the original query used :

```
<cfquery name="qAssociationIdentifierAttributeEncryptedValues" datasource="#variables.dsn#">
    SELECT identifier as attribute_identifiername
        , assoitem.creationdate
        , convert(varchar, month(creationdate)) + '/' + convert(varchar, day(creationdate)) + '/' + convert(varchar, year(creationdate)) as attribute_createdon
        , aap.associationitemid as attribute_identifierid
        , (
            Select DISTINCT u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName + '~'  
            FROM associations_users  au                 
            INNER JOIN "User" u ON u.UserID = au.useridFK 
            WHERE au.associationitemidFK = aap.associationitemid
                AND u.usertype = <cfqueryparam value="Volunteer" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">    
                AND u.programid = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.programid#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
            FOR XML PATH('') 
          ) AS attribute_assignedto
        , CASE WHEN aap.isactive = 1 THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Archived' END AS attribute_status
        , ( 
            SELECT DISTINCT convert(varchar,u.userid) + '~'
            FROM associations_users au                 
            INNER JOIN "User" u ON u.UserID = au.useridFK 
            WHERE au.associationitemidFK = aap.associationitemid
                AND u.usertype = <cfqueryparam value="Volunteer" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">    
                AND u.programid = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.programid#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
            FOR XML PATH('') 
          ) as attribute_assignedtoid
        , ( 
            SELECT u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName + '~'  
            FROM associations_users_tracker aut              
            INNER JOIN "User" u ON u.UserID = aut.useridFK               
            WHERE aut.associationitemidFK = aap.associationitemid   
                AND aut.operationPerformed = <cfqueryparam value="D" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">            
                AND u.usertype = <cfqueryparam value="Volunteer" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">    
                AND u.programid = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.programid#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
            ORDER BY u.LastName,u.FirstName
            FOR XML PATH('') 
          ) as attribute_historicalassignedto
        , (
            SELECT convert(varchar,u.userid) + '~'  
            FROM associations_users_tracker AS aut                  
            INNER JOIN "User" u ON u.UserID = aut.useridFK               
            WHERE aut.associationitemidFK = aap.associationitemid
                AND aut.operationPerformed = <cfqueryparam value="D" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">                
                AND u.usertype = <cfqueryparam value="Volunteer" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">    
                AND u.programid = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.programid#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
            ORDER BY OperationDate,u.LastName,u.FirstName
            FOR XML PATH('') 
          ) as attribute_historicalassignedtoid
        , associationid                           
    FROM association_attribute_#arguments.programid# aap, association_items assoitem             
    WHERE assoitem.associationitemid = aap.associationitemid
        AND associationid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.associationID#">
</cfquery>
```

Every time I'm getting column reference queries of query runtime error.
Even when the column name exists in the query.

> Query Of Queries runtime error. The select column reference Query Of
>   Queries runtime error. The select column reference [attribute_2111] is
>   not a column in any of the tables of the FROM table list.

This is the subquery I'm using:

```
<cfquery name="qAssociationIdentifierAttributeValuesinParts" dbtype="query">
    Select * from qAssociationIdentifierAttributeEncryptedValues        
    Where #ColumnNameFromDBQuery# = #Value#
    ORDER BY attribute_identifiername           
</cfquery>
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Is this `#Value#` a number?

Comment: In your original query, load your data into a memory table and do the sorting off of that.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: First thing, there are several issues with your original query that will cause it to run much slower than it should. After unwinding it, it's mostly made up of a few columns with a bunch of XML that appear to be creating delimited lists. I'm not familiar with your data, but that isn't a great way to work with data. It also uses an old ANSI join to link a dynamic table name with another table. I won't get into the myriad reasons as to why that's not good. IMO, the first thing I'd do is refactor that query to get what you need.

Comment: Second, your QoQ is using dynamic columns and a dynamic (unscoped) value. You have a fixed set of column names that you're working with, so I'm guessing there's some code that picks the one you want. But with the delimited columns, since some of them aren't ordered, you could miss a record you intended because of the order, ie `John~Joe` is not the same as `Joe~John`, but you have no guarantee that the inner queries will return those values in a specific order.

Comment: Regardless, your error indicates that your QoQ is referencing column `attribute_2111` and not one of `attribute_identifiername, creationdate, attribute_createdon, attribute_identifierid, attribute_assignedto, attribute_status, attribute_assignedtoid, attribute_historicalassignedto, attribute_historicalassignedtoid, associationid`. Which brings me back to How is `#ColumnNameFromDBQuery#` being generated for your QoQ?

Comment: I am using SQL server database.

Comment: Query was actually bigger than this, but stackoverflow didn't allowed me to copy it here as it became very large.
[attribute_2111] is one of dynamic column generated in the query.
I dumped the query before the subquery and checked what ever column I'm using in where condition in sub query isthere in the dump but it's giving me error column canont be referenced.

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your question.  Taking out things like `attribute_assignedto` will allow you to put in the code that generates `attribute_2111`.  Also, you can troubleshoot by dumping the variable prior to the QofQ.

Comment: @Ritu I would edit the question and pare the query down to exactly what you want to troubleshoot. Having a dynamically named column that is mentioned in your error is pretty specific to your question. QoQ has some issues itself, so I'm not a huge fan of it. More often than not, what you are actually trying to accomplish can be done in the SQL itself. And using a delimited list in a column, especially when it's used in a `WHERE`, isn't a good use of SQL and is very error-prone. But again, how are you generating `#ColumnNameFromQuery#` and `#Value#` for your QoQ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to encapsulate #Value# with single quotes('):

```
Where #ColumnNameFromDBQuery# = #Value#
```

becomes

```
Where #ColumnNameFromDBQuery# = '#Value#'
```

It looks like CF expects a column name there if it is not encapsulated by single quotes and is not an integer. CF doesn't allow double quotes either.

This will work even when the variable `Value` contains a number which will come in handy cos you are trying to use dynamic column name.